# How to reference the iframe from its contentWindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How can I get a reference to an iframe, if I have the contentWindow of the iframe. The contentWindow is the target from an error. But evt.target.parent just gives me the window from the original page the iframe is on(at least that is what I think).

I need first the iframe and then the container of the iframe (a table)because it holds another object that I need to access(a textarea)

```
    $.fn.setLine= function(target,errorline){

    var target=target;

    var codeLinesDiv = target.parent.parent.parent.find(".codelines");
    codeLinesDiv.children().eq(errorline).css("background-color","red");

    }
```

This will give an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'children

if I use parent() I get:
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'parent' of object [object global] is not a function 
(I don't get this, why doesn't it use the jQuery function parent()  ?)

This is where I call the setLine function

```
   addIframeErrorListener= function(frame){

   handleError= function(evt){ 
   if(evt.message){   alert("error:"+evt.message+"  lineNo:"+ evt.lineno);
   $.fn.setLine(evt.target,evt.lineno);}

   }
   var win=(frame.contentWindow||frame.window);
   addEventListener.call(win,"error",handleError,true);

   }
```

So my question is: how to go from contentWindow to iFrame and the next containet that holds it.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are writing code that will access elements outside of the iframe contents?

Comment: yes, the iframe sits together with a texarea in a table on a html page. I need to access that texarea, or rather the div with codeline numbers that is next to the texarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communication between iframe and parent document is not allowed if your iframe and parent page come from different hosts because it creates a big security hole.

However, if iframe and parent come from the same source (For example: http://mycoolpage.com/iframes and http://mycoolpage.com/parent) you can use **parent.document.getElementById** to get the element you need.

Comment: Yes ,  but can I also get a reference to the iframe and the table it is sitting in, directly from the contenWindow. Because there are more iframes on that page that can each catch an error, and more divs with class : codeLines it would be handy refer to the iframe and then to the tableit was sitting in so I can directly find the correct div with class: codeLines. Is there no method or property to get the physical container from a window

Comment: I do not believe this is possible. Browsers try to keep iframes and parent pages as separate as possible for security reasons. If you have many frames on the page, you should probably give them specific id's that you can easily recognize and search for. This looks like a long way I know, but I think it may be the reason why iframe popularity is not that high.

Comment: Thanks I did what you said and used the id of the frame to derive an id for the specific div(I made sure the divs have similarly numbered ids) , so I could find it. Good to know that an iframe has no connection to the element on the page it sits on except for via the windows of the frame and the page. Thanks